# Responsive points over image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have to build a map of a shopping maal, which will be responsive.

This looks like this on big screen :

[image]

And it looks like this when I reduce the size of my window :
[image: little resolution]

So as you can see the points moves .. Which is not good.

Here is my html  :

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="plan-boutiques"><img src=IMG></img>
    <a href="" id="first_element"><p></p></a>
    <a href="" id="second_element"><p></p></a>
    <a href="" id="third_element"><p></p></a> <!-- There will be 30 elements at the end -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the css I'm using :

```
#plan-boutiques > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 685px;
  max-height: 374px;
 }
.container {
  width:100%; 
  margin:0 auto;
}

 #plan-boutiques a {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display:block;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  position:absolute;
  line-height: 25px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1px;
  background-position: 0 -27px;
 }

#plan-boutiques a:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;
}  
a#first_element {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
<!-- other element have differents margin -->
```

I tried to use % but it's worse it moves a every pixel the window is reduced. Here it only moves when the window is reduced at the max.

**The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vqy8kq2f/**

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) which will then allow us to edit your creation and link back to you.

Comment: ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use percentages if you add to your CSS `#plan-boutiques { display: inline-block; position: relative; }`.

[Here is your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bt0vyu6t/) with my modifications.

Comment: It looks like this is only working with <a> elements. If I try to accomplish it with a div, but same properties as a (inline-bloc, margin, pos-absolute) then I don't see it, unless I specify top.bot pos

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `width: 100%` from `#plan-boutiques > img`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qun26gnt/)

**EDIT**

So i added some jQuery to calculate exact location of the dots and recalculate it if the image gets smaller than the mentioned size

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mkk9dr4a/1/)

ps: you will have to click run every time you resize the box. Also you can add `$(window).resize()` function if you want a real time response.

Comment: In this way the image is no longer responsive.